# Error with tomcat web hosting..Says I have missing bean? But works well in localhost

Tags: javascript, java, spring, tomcat

I am new to web applications and I made a simple homepage using java Spring. I purchased a tomcat web server and I am trying to get my homepage to load. I exported my project as a war file and uploaded them under the ROOT of my server. I think the error is saying it cannot find the 'commentController' because of a missing bean...? However my program works fine on the localhost and I never had any bean errors so I am confused. The following is the error I keep getting.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet action threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet action threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet action threw exception
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:64)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commentController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'photoService' is defined
    org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:64)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'photoService' is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1114)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:279)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:270)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:445)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:419)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:547)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:64)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.32 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: make sure you packed all necessary libraries with either war file or tomcat library folder, are you debugging the app with eclipse?

Comment: @user5266804 Yes. But it worked fine on eclipse localhost. I am trying to get this to run on an actual tomcat server. And it shows me that error..

Comment: So note that, eclipse doesn't uses the `server.xml` config files which is located in default conf folder, same about the `context.xml`, so when you pack the war, it might contains the wrong config files. In eclipse, in project(or package) panel(where you see the project stuffs as tree), find a project/stuff called server, simply try to find out where is this located (usually in default workspace), your correct config files are there, have a try

Comment: If you drill down the exception stack trace it says that `photoService` bean is not defined. Is this bean defined in separate config file which is not part of your war ? If you could post the relevant config it would be helpful

Comment: @user5266804 you're right!... I went in to my workspace and there is a red exclamation mark next to some files and I opened my problem view and there is an error: Description Resource Path Location Type
Class 'org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean' is marked deprecated [config set: Sample.Test002/web-context] context-sqlMap.xml /Sample.Test002/src/main/resources/egovframework/spring line 6 Spring Beans Problem
I will try and figure this out at least this is a step forward thx!